# Working with Recursion and Generic Interfaces

Tags: java, generics, recursion

I have three generic interfaces (with an inverses relationship between two of them) and want to process them in a recursive method:

```
public interface User<R extends Role<R,U>, U extends User<R,U>>
{
  public R getRole();
  public void setRole(R role);
}

public interface Role<R extends Role<R,U>,U extends User<R,U>>
{
  public List<R> getRoles();
  public void setRoles(List<R> roles);

  public List<U> getUser() ;
  public void setUser(List<U> user);
}
```

Now I want to do some processing with a recursion in my `Worker` class:

```
public <R extends Role<R,U>,U extends User<R,U>> void recursion(List<R> roles)
{
  for(R role : roles)
  {
    recursion(role.getRoles());
  }
}
```

I get this error and I'm didn't figured out why this does not work or how I can solve this:

```
Bound mismatch: The generic method recursion(List<R>) of type Worker is not
applicable for the arguments (List<R>). The inferred type User<R,User<R,U>>
is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <U extends User<R,U>>
```

Answer (score 2):

I modified it, without using generic wildcards `?`, so it compiles.
After stripping out method declarations irrelevant to the problem:

```
public interface Role<R extends Role<R, U>, U extends User<R, U>> {
    public List<Role<R, U>> getRoles(); // Change here to return type
}

public interface User<R extends Role<R, U>, U extends User<R, U>> { // No change
}

// Change to method parameter type
public static <R extends Role<R, U>, U extends User<R, U>> void recursion(List<Role<R, U>> roles) {
    for (Role<R, U> role : roles) { // Change to element type
        recursion(role.getRoles());
    }
}
```

I hope these changes still fit your design - let me know if they don't work for you and I'll try to work around your requirements.

Phew! Tough one!

Comment: I'm unsure about the implication of changing the interface method for `Role`. I assume it returns a List of the interface of `Role`. I'm using the interfaces for some `@Entity` implementations. The recursive method is used in one utility class, perhaps the wildcard proposal `?` of dacwe is suitable for me.

Answer (score 1):

As you have noticed you need to specify the type `U` in one of the arguments. You can do that or if you want to ignore the `U` type you can use `?` instead:

```
public <R extends Role<R,?>> void recursion(List<R> roles)
{
  for(R role : roles)
  {
    recursion(role.getRoles());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this may be a solution for me problem. But normally I only use the wildcard `?` if I really don't know the type. Here I'm sure it is of type `U`.

Comment: Then you could to pass another parameter with that "type information", for example: `... recursion(List<R> roles, Class<U> userClass)` (and ignore the parameter)..